# Found the Space Core in Skyrim, what can I do with it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Valve and Bethesda have made all my dreams come true by [putting the Space Core into Skyrim](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=7375).

Obviously there is the usual tossing and kicking, but I've heard that it can be used as a crafting ingredient as well?

**What is the Space Core good for, once I have it?**

Comment: Haha amazing :)

Comment: Dad, are you space?

Comment: I think playing football with it is proper use. ;)

Comment: Space core in the past eh? I guess time really is cyclical, [99999999999...9](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=TE67EpU9u40#t=132s) days later.

Comment: Maybe they just wanted to put something in that's voiced by Nolan North?

Comment: @Resorath Gotta nitpick here. The Elder Scrolls doesn't necessarily take place in the past relative to Earth.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In addition to it saying various SPAAAACE and Skyrim-related puns, you can also apparently take it into the midden under the College of Winterhold and create a Dovacore Helmet:

Put the space core on the pedestal, and make an offering of 8 refined moonstone (moonstone ore might also be acceptable) and an iron helmet.  Pull the lever, and out pops a shiny new helmet.  It looks like you can pick up the Space Core again when this is finished, so it is not consumed in the process.

Comment: There's also a rumor that there's a [secret Portal-related quest](http://www.geekosystem.com/skyrim-portal-2-quest/) that is part of this DLC...  if I learn more, I'll update the answer :)

Answer (score 8):

Even if you haven't found the Space Core yet, you'll also occasionally see Wheatly floating around in space. Specifically, on the Skills menu.

[image: Skills menu with Space Core]

Comment: The one floating through the skills menu is not the space core its Wheatley from Portal2